# Permutations of Number sequence with Minimum cost

Tags: logic, optimization, permutations, contest-math, computer-science

There are numbers from 1 to N and our task is to create a permutation such that the cost of the permutation is minimum. For each number, there is a left and right cost. To put number p (i<=p<=N) at the  ith (1-based index) index, it costs Lp*(i-1) + Rp*(N-i) where L[] (left array) and R[] (right array) cost is given. (size of Left[] and Right are same = N)

We do not need to find that permutation but we need to find the total minimum possible cost of the permutation.

Example:- N = 3
L[] (left array) = {1,2,6}
R[] (right array)  = {4,7,2}

Answer = 13..because possible permutation is {3,1,2} and cost = (0 * 6 + 2 * 2) + (1 * 1 + 1 * 4) + (2 * 2 + 0 * 4) = 13 which is minimum possible cost.

My approach:-

```
As Lp*(i-1) + Rp*(N-i) is a Summation from i = 1 to N, tried to figure out a common formula for this as

Lp*(1-1) + Rp*(N-1) + Lp*(2-1) + Rp*(N-2) + Lp*(3-1) + Rp*(N-3) ...... Lp*(N-1) + Rp*(N-N)

=> Lp*(0) + Rp*(N-1) + Lp*(1) + Rp*(N-2) + Lp*(3) + Rp*(N-3) ..... Lp*(N-1) + Rp*(0)

=> Lp*(((N-1) * N)/2) + Rp*(((N-1) * N)/2) OR (((N-1) * N)/2)*(Lp + Rp)
```

After that, I put Lp and Rp values from the Left array and right array respectively to get minimum cost, but this is not working.

Can any please help me to solve these questions? (Or please tell me if I am mistaking somewhere or breaking maths rules in my derivation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an instance of the [linear assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  For $(p,i)\in\{1,\dots,N\}^2$, let $$c_{p,i} = L[p](i-1)+R[p](N-i)$$ be the cost of assigning number $p$ to position $i$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{p,i}$ indicate whether this assignment is made. The problem is to minimize $\sum_{p,i} c_{p,i} x_{p,i}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_{p,i} &= 1 &&\text{for all $p$}\\ 
\sum_p x_{p,i} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}\\ 
\end{align}
For your example, the cost matrix is
$$c=\begin{pmatrix}
8 &5 &2\\ 
14 &9 &4\\ 
4 &8 &12 
\end{pmatrix}$$ and the problem is to minimize
$$8x_{1,1} + 5x_{1,2} + 2x_{1,3}  
+ 14x_{2,1} + 9x_{2,2} + 4x_{2,3}  
+ 4x_{3,1} + 8x_{3,2} + 12x_{3,3} 
$$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_{1,1} + x_{1,2} + x_{1,3} &= 1 \\ 
x_{2,1} + x_{2,2} + x_{2,3} &= 1 \\ 
x_{3,1} + x_{3,2} + x_{3,3} &= 1 \\ 
x_{1,1} + x_{2,1} + x_{3,1} &= 1 \\ 
x_{1,2} + x_{2,2} + x_{3,2} &= 1 \\ 
x_{1,3} + x_{2,3} + x_{3,3} &= 1 \\ 
\end{align}
The optimal solution has $x_{1,2}=x_{2,3}=x_{3,1}=1$ and all other $x_{p,i}=0$, yielding optimal objective value $c_{1,2}+c_{2,3}+c_{3,1}=5+4+4=13$.

Comment: Hi @RobPratt sir... I don't get your logic.. Can you please explain it with example i have mentioned in question..?

Comment: I added your example just now.

Comment: But sir My example contains only 2 arrays..i.e Left and right array....  How 3x3 matrix is possible for that

Comment: The matrix $c_{p,i}$ is defined for each $p \in \{1,2,3\}$ and $i \in \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: okay  so first Coloumn represent cost at i = 1..?  and so on..isn't it..?

Comment: Yes, the rows of the cost matrix are indexed by $p$, and the columns are indexed by $i$.

Comment: Thanks @RobPratt sir..Great explaination..Sir is there any direct way (or formula) which will give me optimal solution by using minimum loops..?

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.  Two natural solution methods are linear programming or the Hungarian algorithm.

Comment: actually i showed example with N = 3,  I have to find a method for N = N where 1<=N<=100000. So, i am unable to program this in C++. But you solution is great sir. I learned how to approach problems like this from you solution

Answer (score 0):

If you rearrange your cost, it becomes $(L_p-R_p)*i+(R_p*N-L_p)$. Note that the only part in the expression which is multiplied by $i$ is $(L_p-R_p)$ and the rest is constant, i.e, no matter how you try to arrange your numbers, this part is always going to add up into the answer. Therefore an optimal strategy would be to sort our array on the basis $(L_p-R_p)$ in decreasing manner and then take the sum of $i*(L_p-R_p)$ over all $1<=i<=N$.